# About Painting Bump texture

Tags: texturing

[image]When i try to paint Bump texture on cube its outline appears to be distorted. I have used 4k Bump image.Could anyone tell how to make bump painting smooth.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

here is a 1024x1024 example.

go to shader editor and make the first option in image texture to cubic or smart.